# node express + typescript module not found error

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Ive setup a simple node express app with typescript.

I want to add a errorMiddleware in the index.ts file.

When I start the server I am getting this error:

```
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ActiveProjects\rugBE\src\index.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1371:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1374:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\ActiveProjects\\rugBE\\src\\index.ts' ]
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rugbe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.19",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

tsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "Handlers/*": ["Handlers/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

index.ts:

```
import express from "express";
import errorMiddleWare from "Handlers/Error/handlerError"; // error here
// import notFoundMiddleWare from "Handlers/Error/notFound";
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

//@ts-ignore
app.get("/api", (_, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

//notFound

// error
app.use(errorMiddleWare);

// app.all("*", notFoundMiddleWare);

app.listen(port);
```

The middleWare I am trying to import:

```
//@ts-ignore
const errorMiddleWare = (err, req, res, next) => {
  // note params are the ones that tell if the errors should come here
  const { statusCode, message } = err;
  res.status(500).json({
    status: "error",
    statusCode: 500,
    message,
  });

  next();
};

export default errorMiddleWare;
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handlers` is an "bare" path. When you tell node to import a file starting not starting with a `/` or `./` (or `../`) it will look for a module in your `node_modules` directory with that name.

In order to add a file relative to your current directory (and other files) prefix it with `./`. The full algorithm is specified [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#all-together) if you want the full picture of how cjs (CommonJS modules) module loading works.

```
// Before, loads a Handlers package from node_modules
import errorMiddleWare from "Handlers/Error/handlerError"; // error here

// After, looks for a handlerError module in an
// Error folder inside the Handlers folder inside the current one
import errorMiddleWare from "./Handlers/Error/handlerError"; // error here
```

Comment: Isn't there a way for me to configure this so that I can have the path like this and tell the compiler not to look in node-modules? Thats why I added paths in the tsconfig and the exclude of node modules in tsconfig aswell. You are correct that "./" works but I am trying to have it direct.

Comment: @CodingLittle yes, either with https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths (using the same sort of config you are using for cjs). That package exists for this use case. I don't like it (because module resolution is hard enough as it is to figure out) but it's a possibility and YMMV :)

Comment: I might be asking alot from you in this answer but Im struggling to get it to work. I installed the linked package but getting the same error.

Comment: @CodingLittle feel free to open concrete isolated questions and ping me, I can't help with "It doesn't work" and the original answer demonstrates you know how to ask here. (After installing that package make sure you follow its instructions and specify `Handlers` in your tsconfig.json's "paths" section.